# How do I get a list of authors and committer IDs in a Git pre-commit hook?

Tags: git, validation, pre-commit-hook

It seems there is no simple way to get authors and committer IDs in a Git pre-commit hook ([Missing git hooks documentation](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/)).

I can only find [examples for post-commit hooks](http://www.sitepoint.com/git-hooks-fun-profit/) which, for example, look for spelling mistakes and then suggest

> If there are errors, you can immediately fix the commit message by running `git commit --amend`.

which seems kind of too late.

Is there really no way to get this information in a pre-commit hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  The commit does not yet exist so there's nothing to get.

You can come pretty close: use the same rules that `git commit` uses to pick a default author and committer, i.e., look for `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` in the environment, and if not set, use `git config --get user.name`, etc., to get the settings.  But this does not seem to capture any `--author=` argument to a `git commit` command.

Comment: Thanks. We're not using `--author` (or at least I hope EGit doesn't), so this should be OK.